# EXCEL - Sub Total Function

Tags: excel-2010

I know how to use Subtotal when I only need a breakdown by 1 column.  But I have a sheet with 2 sort level.  I need to get counts based on values for each of the second level sort.  To clarify, I need something like this: assuming Col A is primary sort and Col B is secondary.

```
A            B       Count

Walmart    Shoes       20
----------
Walmart    Socks       10




Walmart    Shirts      25

Target     Socks       50


Target     Jeans       5 


Target      Shirts     10
```

etc... (Not sure how to make this prettier(more readable).

Can the Subtotal function do this or do I have to get into Pivot Tables (Group, etc)?  Thanks in advance?

Comment: Does the name of the store need to appear in every row of column A?

Comment: No - definitely not on every row.  But would need it once to know the counts for that store.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be a situation that would call for a Pivot Table. 
[image]

To create the pivot table select one of the cells in the raw data (Columns A through C in the picture). Then select the Insert Tab >> PivotTable >> PivotTable. You'll have the choice of putting the PivotTable on another worksheet or the one that contains the data (as shown).
Check A, B and C as seen in the picture, the choice of area should be done automatically, however if one of them does not automatically appear in the correct area (as shown) you can drag it. 
Under PivotTable Tools select the Design tab and then Report Layout and Show in Tabular Form. 
To the left of Report Layout is Grand Totals which you would  turn off to make the pivot table look more like the table in your example. 
To the right of Grand Totals is Subtotals which you would also turn off by choosing Do not show.
If it is important that Walmart precede Target, select the down arrow in PivotTable cell containing A (E2 in the picture), and sort Z to A.
Hope this helps.